# Rust ownership issues

Tags: networking, rust, ownership, mio

I'm quite new to Rust, I'm mainly a C#, javascript and python developer, so I like to approach things in a OOP way, however I still can't wrap my head around ownership in rust. Especially when it comes to OOP.

I'm writing a TCP server. I have a struct that contains connections (streams) and I read the sockets asynchronously using the mio crate. I understand what the error is telling me, but I have no clue how to fix it. I tried changing the read_message method into a function (without the reference to self), which worked, but the problem with this is that I'll need to access the connections and whatnot from the struct (to relay messages between sockets for example), so this workaround won't be plausible in later versions. Is there an easy fix for this, or is the design inherently flawed?

Here's a snippet that shows what my problem is:

```
let sock = self.connections.get_mut(&token).unwrap();
loop {
    match sock.read(&mut msg_type) {
        Ok(_) => {
            self.read_message(msg_type[0], token);
        }
    }
}

fn read_message(&mut self, msg_type: u8, token: Token) {
    let sock = self.connections.get_mut(&token).unwrap();
    let msg_type = num::FromPrimitive::from_u8(msg_type);
    match msg_type {
        Some(MsgType::RequestIps) => {
            let decoded: MsgTypes::Announce = bincode::deserialize_from(sock).unwrap();
            println!("Public Key: {}", decoded.public_key);
        }
        _ => unreachable!()
    } 
}
```

And the error I'm getting is the following:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are holding a mutable borrow on `sock`, which is part of `self`, at the moment you try to call `self.read_message`. Since you indicated that `read_message` needs mutable access to all of `self`, you need to make sure you don't have a mutable borrow on `sock` anymore at that point.

Fortunately, thanks to non-lexical lifetimes in Rust 2018, that's not hard to do; simply fetch `sock` inside the loop:

```
loop {
    let sock = self.connections.get_mut(&token).unwrap();
    match sock.read(&mut msg_type) {
        Ok(_) => {
            self.read_message(msg_type[0], token);
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming `sock.read` doesn't return anything that holds a borrow on `sock`, this should let the mutable borrow on `sock` be released before calling `self.read_message`. It needs to be re-acquired in the next iteration, but seeing as you're doing network I/O, the relative performance penalty of a single `HashMap` (?) access should be negligible.

(Due to lack of a minimal, compileable example, I wasn't able to test this.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Despite the lack of a proper example you understood my question perfectly.